# Referencing the is-invalid and :invalid pseudoclass of bootstrap form validation with jQuery to to run code only when form is valid

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, forms, validation

Here is the code

```
 $("#enterform").on("click", function (event) {
      if ((($(".was-validated").children().hasClass(":invalid"))===false)&&(($(".was-validated").children().hasClass(".is-invalid"))===false))
      {code i want to run that is running no matter what}
```

so you see, i imagine if form validation is working, then when one of these children has class .is-invalid the code in the code block should not run, except it does.

Comment: I'm not entirely you can use a pseudoselector in `hasClass()`.  As ':invalid' is not a class

Comment: https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.hasClass  Yeah, I don't think that's going to work.  It's looking for that to be a class.

Comment: Thanks, still trying to figure how to differentiate between everything being valid and not.

Comment: seems that referencing something like ".form-check-input:valid" as a class also yields no results.

Comment: because `hasClass()` is not expecting it's input to be a selector.  It should be a *concrete* literal class name.